# Material input label doesn't show correctly after changing font

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have material input with `floatLabel='always'` option. When I change font family material doesn't calculate label width and the label isn't shown correctly.

[image]

How can I solve this ? Example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/a-material-font?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the border isn't updating if you change the font, which makes sense since nothing tells it to update, so there doesn't seem to be a way to make it automatically calculate the border size.

Here is a slightly 'hacky' way to update the label, basically we re-create the form field to apply the changes, this will however, get rid of any input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/a-material-font-d8vpb9

Putting the `*ngIf` on the label sadly doesn't work, it just removes it and never re-creates it.